# what is the best practice for communication between child and parent components from the child end?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get input in the child's component set the state with it, and then pass it to the parent and set the state there with the passing data - fortunately it happens with some delay: lets say the input is: "1", the child state is blank - and then I add "2", so the child state should be "12" but its only "1"- can someone help me figure it out please?

```html
class PropertyCard extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        label:'',
        name:'',
        type:'',  
    };
    this.ChangeLabel = this.ChangeLabel.bind(this);
  }

  ChangeLabel = (updatedName) => {
    console.log("updatedName: "+updatedName);
    this.setState({label: updatedName});
    console.log(this.state.label);
  }

  CreateJson = () => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <WizardField 
          label={'label'}
          type={'text'}
          name={this.state.label} 
          onUpdate={this} 
          handleChange={this.ChangeLabel}
          />

          <button 
          style={{marginTop:"10px" }}
          className="ui primary button"
          variant="primary"
          onClick={this.CreateJson}
          >Done!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }

class WizardField extends React. Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      name:this.props.name
    };
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
};

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
    console.log("state in child: "+this.state.name);
    this.props.handleChange(this.state.name);
    }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <label>
          {this.props.label}:
        </label>
        <input 
          type={this.props.type}
          value={this.state.name} 
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You might find the third paragraph (the one in bold) interesting. This whole section talks about communication between components: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the method you passed via props

```
function WizardField({label, name, handleChange, type="text") {
  return(
    <div>
      <label>
        {label}:
      </label>
      <input 
        type={type}
        value={name} 
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

you need to update the handleChange handler as well.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
}
```

Comment: but I have to update the child state before calling the parent function via props

Comment: why? you're maintaining the same state in two components

Comment: why is it a function? did you mean a functional component?  I tried it, but the parent state does not update correctly

Comment: just try it :) its just a functional component

Comment: I get "[object Object]" in the parent component state

Comment: you have to update the parent handler ill post an update

Comment: You're welcome! when you are able to remember to click that check mark so we can resolve this question.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data from child to parent you would use events with callback functions:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html